# Are the members of a Jacobian matrix necessarily real numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, jacobian

According to the definition of the Jacobian on Wikipedia:

> [image]

I've seen it written elsewhere that the members of a Jacobian matrix are all real numbers. But in case $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m > 1$, then aren't each of the $\partial f_i / \partial x_j \in \mathbb{R}^m$?

**Question:**

Comment: Each $f_i$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, so the derivative with respect to $x_j$ is another function from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\partial f_i/\partial x_j$ is the partial derivative of $f_i$ with respect to $x_j$. It is a scalar-valued function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because each $f_i$ is a *real* function, and therefore each $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

No, for example let $f(x,y) = (x^2,y^2,xy)$ then
$$
\mathcal{J} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \left[x^2\right]}{\partial x} &
\frac{\partial \left[x^2\right]}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial \left[y^2\right]}{\partial x} &
\frac{\partial \left[y^2\right]}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial [xy ]}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial [xy ]}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2x &  0 \\
 0 & 2y \\
 y &  x
\end{pmatrix}
$$